# Как сделать одинаковый отступ между элементами, но кроме краев контейнера?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, flexbox

[image: без флексов и js]

(1 картинка)

У контейнера может меняться ширина. У элементов фиксированная ширина 75px, margin-left 20px. Как можно сделать, что бы элементы равномерно распределились?

ссылка на мою разметку:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/mefpu0k6/1/
```

[image: space-between]

Если делать через flex-wrap и space-between, то у последних элементов margin-left не такой как у всех (2 картинка)

[image: с использованием js]

А нужно сделать как на 3 картинке. Т.е margin-left у всех одинаковый

Мне удалось это сделать, но только с помощью js

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/u1yub2jq/2/`
```

Можно ли это сделать без помощи js? Или что делать с лишним пространством справа?

При этом, когда меняется ширина элементы переходят на новую строку.

Comment: Как вариант - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/u1yub2jq/3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не флексбоком единым. Есть ещё грид.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 75px);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  justify-content: space-between;

  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  font: 20px sans-serif;
  line-height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">1</div>
  <div class="block">2</div>
  <div class="block">3</div>
  <div class="block">4</div>
  <div class="block">5</div>
  <div class="block">6</div>
  <div class="block">7</div>
  <div class="block">8</div>
</div>
```

Подробный разбор всех вариантов размещения ячеек с разнообразными выравниваниями можно найти в статье 
[**Красивое выравнивание блоков по резиновой сетке. По-новому**](http://css-live.ru/css/responsive-grid-css-grid-layout-auto-fill.html)
.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 480px;
  height: 220px;
  background: rgba(205, 115, 12, 0.1);
  border: 0.1px solid rgba(205, 115, 12, 1);
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: baseline;
  align-content: space-between;
}

.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если вы поставите `width: 580px`, то заметите, что не ответили на поставленный вопрос, а просто привели одну из итераций автора вопроса.